# Google Cloud Invalid value for [ACCOUNT]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to upload a dockerfile to the Google Cloud containers.

Turns out, this is more difficult than actual developing the app.

I did everything the authenticaion page mentioned (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud-helper), but then i had to set up a key.

I followed this guide (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys), downloaded my json file.

I could not use gcloud shell, so i downloaded gcloud in my local machine from snaps.

Finally issued this command:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT --key-file=KEY-FILE
```

Where

ACCOUNT is the service account name in the format [USERNAME]@[PROJECT-ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com. You can view existing service accounts on the Service Accounts page of Cloud Console or with the command gcloud iam service-accounts list
KEY-FILE is the service account key file. See the Identity and Access Management (IAM) documentation for information about creating a key.

However, i get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Invalid value for [ACCOUNT]: The given account name does not match the account name in the key file.  This argument can be omitted when using .json keys.
```

I don't know neither what is going on, or why i am getting this error, since i am doing everything by the book.
Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to run `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=KEY-FILE` (without `[ACCOUNT]`) ?

Comment: @norbjd This worked but then when i did a docker push, i got `WARNING: Could not open the configuration file: [/root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default].`

Comment: Does the warning prevent you from pushing your image ? Anyway, maybe you can try to run `gcloud config set account [ACCOUNT]`.

Comment: Yes, i cannot push it. What do i put in ACCOUNT? I had problems since nothing worked with ACCOUNT before.

Comment: `gcloud config set account [USERNAME]@[PROJECT-ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com` should be OK.